# I use MSAL to authenticate with a Microsoft account in my Angular application. I am able to access the user name. I have trouble in finding the image

Tags: angular, azure, authentication, project, msal-angular

In Appmodule
{
interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
protectedResourceMap: new Map([
[
'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me',
['user.Read', 'email', 'profile'],
],
['/api/', ['api://***7bb5-8***********f/api.scope']],
]),
}
In Component
private checkLogin() {
if (!this.isUserLoggedIn) {
this.router.navigate([this.router.url]);
this.callProfile();
} else {
if (this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest) {
this.msalService.loginRedirect({
...this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest,
} as RedirectRequest);
} else {
this.msalService.loginRedirect();
}
}
}

private callProfile() {
this.httpClient.get("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me").subscribe(
(resp: GraphApiResponse) => {
console.log('User ID:', resp.id);
this.generateImageSource(resp);
},
(error) => {
console.error('Error fetching profile:', error);
}
);
}
But i am to fetch user id but in image giving  404
generateImageSource ID: ****e////******///a2**
graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/****e//*********/a2**/photo/$value:1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
Please help me to fetch user profile there is no access problem from azure.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way i am able to fetch username and image

**1: Installed MSAL for Angular**

```
npm install --save @azure/msal-angular 
npm install --save @azure/msal-browser
```

**2: Created a component to display user information**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { MsalService } from '@azure/msal-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  template: `
    <h1>User Profile</h1>
    <div *ngIf="isAuthenticated">
      <h2>Welcome, {{ userDisplayName }}</h2>
      <img [src]="userImageUrl" alt="User Image" />
    </div>
  `,
})
export class ProfileComponent {
  isAuthenticated: boolean = false;
  userDisplayName: string | undefined;
  userImageUrl: string | undefined;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private msalService: MsalService) {
    this.isAuthenticated = this.msalService.instance.getAllAccounts().length > 0;
    if (this.isAuthenticated) {
      const user = this.msalService.instance.getAllAccounts()[0];
      this.userDisplayName = user.name || 'User';
      this.userImageUrl = user.idTokenClaims ? user.idTokenClaims['upn'] : 'default-image-url';
    }
  }
}
```

**3.Configure the MSAL Module**:
In your `app.module.ts`, make sure you've set up the required scopes to access the Microsoft Graph API. This will include the `User.Read` scope.

```
const  GRAPH_ENDPOINT  =  'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me';
export  function  MSALInterceptorConfigFactory():  MsalInterceptorConfiguration {

const  protectedResourceMap  =  new  Map<string, Array<string>>();
protectedResourceMap.set(GRAPH_ENDPOINT, ['user.read']);
return {
interactionType:  InteractionType.Redirect,
protectedResourceMap,
};
}
```

**Result**
[image]

[image]

[image]